# How to convert string to isolatedfilestream?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

convert string to isolatedfilestream? i am trying to convert string in to isolatedfilestream and re-write in XML file on wp7. can any one suggest me. thank in advance

Comment: you can store the string directly. and retrieve it from isolated storage as a string and use XML parser to get the data.
or do you want to know how to store a string/XML data in an isolatedstorage

Comment: How far have you got? What have you tried, and what went wrong? (Also, what do you mean by "rewrite" in this case? It's really unclear what you're trying to achieve.)

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to store and retrieve only XML data, please check the following tutorial. It will help you in understanding how to store XML data.

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/All-about-WP7-Isolated-Storage---Read-and-Save-XML-files-using-XmlWriter

additionally do check the following tutorial when you want to save large amount of data, specifically when u want to store an object of a class. This will teach you how to store and retrieve data using XMLserializer, this will also maintain the entire sequence of data stored.

http://rushabh.greenpoison.org.in/blog/2012/06/07/local-windows-phone-7-database-using-xmlserializer/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IsolatedFileStream` like any other stream, to a large extent. So any way that you would write to a stream on the desktop (e.g. `XmlWriter.Create(stream)`) should be fine. For files small enough to load into memory, I'd personally use LINQ to XML most of the time - again, you can load that from a stream, and then save it to an `XmlWriter` wrapping an `IsolatedFileStream`.

I would recommend *against* loading the XML as a string first and then parsing it; if you load it directly from the stream, you allow the parser to handle the declared text encoding itself, rather than you having to do it.